# Android and Crypto++ AES 128bit encrypted results not matching

Tags: android, c++, encryption, crypto++, javax.crypto

I am trying to use the same key and VI to encrypt and decryp the same message, say `aabbcc@gmail.com`. The key length is 128 bit as I know that in Java/Android, 256 is not easy to implement.

Here is my function to do the AES encryption using Crypto++

```
string encryptString(string toBeEncrypted) {
//
// Create Cipher Text
//
CryptoPP::AES::Encryption aesEncryption(key, CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Encryption cbcEncryption(aesEncryption, iv);

std::string ciphertext;

std::cout << "To be encrypted (" << toBeEncrypted.size() << " bytes)" << std::endl;
std::cout << toBeEncrypted;
std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;

CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter stfEncryptor(cbcEncryption, new CryptoPP::StringSink(ciphertext), CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter::PKCS_PADDING);
stfEncryptor.Put(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*> (toBeEncrypted.c_str()), toBeEncrypted.length() + 1);
stfEncryptor.MessageEnd();

}
```

key is "4ff539a893fed04840749287bb3e4152" and IV is "79f564e83be16711759ac7c730072bd0".

They are stored in binary in a ubuntu running in VMWare on a x86 Windows.

The function to convert `key` and `iv` from byte to hex array is:

```
std::string hexToStr(unsigned char *data, int len)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss<<std::hex;
    for(int i(0);i<len;++i){
        ss<<std::setfill('0')<<std::setw(2)<<(int)data[i];
    }

return ss.str();
}
```

I checked the hex string vs the memory of byte array `key` and `iv`, and they are matching.

The results for encrypting `aabbcc@gmail.com` is `c08a50b45ff16650542e290e05390a6c6fe533e11e9f802ad7d47681fd41f964` from C++.

I obtained this by passing the returned string `ciphertext` into the function `hexToStr` like `cout<<TFFHelper::hexStr((unsigned char *)ciphertext.c_str(), ciphertext.length())<<endl;`

I can also decrpt it with the following function, and I passed the raw string rather than the hex string into this function.

```
string TFFEncryption::decryptString(string toBeDecrypted) {

string decryptedtext;
CryptoPP::AES::Decryption aesDecryption(key, CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Decryption cbcDecryption(aesDecryption, iv);

CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter stfDecryptor(cbcDecryption, new CryptoPP::StringSink(decryptedtext), CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter::PKCS_PADDING);
stfDecryptor.Put(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*> (toBeDecrypted.c_str()), toBeDecrypted.size());
stfDecryptor.MessageEnd();

return decryptedtext;
}
```

---

I put the same VI and KEY in my Android code, and try to encrypt. It ends up in a half matching results after encrypting.

Android code is as follow:

```
public class myAES {
private static final String key = "4ff539a893fed04840749287bb3e4152";
private static final String initVector = "79f564e83be16711759ac7c730072bd0";
private final  static char[] hexArray = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();

public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
    int len = s.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
        data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
    }
    return data;
}

public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
    char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
    for ( int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++ ) {
        int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
        hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
        hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
    }
    return new String(hexChars);
}

public static byte[] encrypt(String value) {
    try {
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(hexStringToByteArray(initVector));
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(hexStringToByteArray(key), "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);

        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes());
        Log.v("Encryption successful", bytesToHex(encrypted));
        return encrypted;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public static String decrypt(byte[] encrypted) {
    try {
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(hexStringToByteArray(initVector));
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(hexStringToByteArray(key), "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);

        byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
        Log.v("Decryption successful", new String(original, "UTF-8"));
        return new String(original);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

I got the result of `C08A50B45FF16650542E290E05390A6CFE5466FC480F0667517B248410930B69`.

I used the same piece of code in Netbeans on Java8, running on the same Ubuntu of the C++ code, and got exactly the same results as what I mentioned on the previous line (Android results). I don't think this is OS dependent, but probably I did something wrong with either Java or C++ in my code.

So the first half of the hex strings are matching, and the later half is not. I tried to reduced the phrase `aabbcc@gmail.com` into `abc@gmail.com`, which results in complete different results from C++ vs Java (Ubuntu vs Android).

However, if I decrpt that binary array in Java, I got the original phrase `aabbcc@gmail.com` or `abc@gmail.com`.

I have the following questions.

1. What did I do wrong?
2. Is it the proper way to case `const char *` into `unsigned char *`? I think it should be OK as I am getting the hex string of the binary
3. Is the half matching results caused by padding?

Comment: Which version of Crypto++ are you using ?

Comment: Crypto++ provides a [`HexDecoder`](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/HexDecoder). You can use it in place of `std::string hexToStr(...)` if you like.

Comment: apt-cache showpkg libcrypto++9v5
Package: libcrypto++9v5
Versions: 
5.6.1-9 (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial_universe_binary-amd64_Packages) (/var/lib/dpkg/status)

Comment: I used the same piece of code in Netbeans on Java8, running on the same Ubuntu of the C++ code, and got exactly the same results as running on Android. I don't think this is OS dependent, but probably I did something wrong with either Java or C++ in my code.

Comment: @jww It's `HexEncoder` by the way, and it returns exactly the same hex string comparing to using my own `hexToStr`.

Comment: I actually tried to decrypt both hex strings (1 from encryption in C++, 1 from encryption in Java), and both of them gives me the same original text aabbcc@gmail.com, however, if I decrypt in Java using the encrypted hex string from C++, I got some extra character after `aabbcc@gmail.com`.

I agree that I did not really know the fundamental of AES encryption. Can someone with the insight to shed some light?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The email in the **Crypto++** message is `'0'` terminated, but the message in **Java** is not.

As **AES** is a block cipher with a block length of 128 bits (16 bytes), and your email is exactly 16 bytes long, the first block gets encrypted the same way in both implementations. The `'0'` in the first position of the second block gives the difference in the second block of the encryption.

Notice the extra `'00'` in below screenshot using [this online tool](http://aes.online-domain-tools.com/). All the `'0f'` following the `'00'` is the **PKCS5 Padding** that this tool did not remove here ..

[image]

Comment: I thought the temination was not encrypted... thanks